# Counting records by type in union query

Tags: sql, sqlite, union

I have a sqlite3 database with two tables 'messages' and 'svd', they contain similar information and share certain fields, such as message_type, but other than that are sufficiently different to warrant separate tables.

I want to create a query that counts the number of message types over both tables.

This works fine for the tables individually, but produces false results when used in a UNION. I don't understand what's going wrong, can anyone help shed some light on this?

Individual message_type counts for each table:

```
SELECT message_type AS ID, message_types.type AS Type, count(*) as MsgCount FROM messages
       INNER JOIN message_types ON messages.message_type = message_types.ID
       GROUP BY message_type ORDER BY MsgCount DESC'
```

This produces the anticipated result:

```
ID          Type                                                   MsgCount  
----------  -----------------------                                ----------
1           Position Report Class A                                96513     
3           Position Report Class A (Response to interrogation)    46265     
18          Standard Class B CS Position Report                    11098     
11          UTC and Date Response                                  961       
10          UTC and Date Inquiry                                   452
```

For the SVD table, this is the query:

```
SELECT message_type AS ID, message_types.type AS Type, count(*) as MsgCount FROM svd
       INNER JOIN message_types ON svd.message_type = message_types.ID
       GROUP BY message_type ORDER BY MsgCount DESC'
```

and the result:

```
ID          Type                            MsgCount  
----------  ------------------------------  ----------
5           Static and Voyage Related Data  4746      
24          Static Data Report              3250
```

Now the UNION code should produce a combined result, but it doesn't. The query:

```
SELECT message_type AS ID, message_types.type AS Type, count(*) as MsgCount FROM messages
       INNER JOIN message_types ON messages.message_type = message_types.ID
UNION
SELECT message_type AS ID, message_types.type AS Type, count(*) as MsgCount FROM svd
       INNER JOIN message_types ON svd.message_type = message_types.ID
GROUP BY message_type ORDER BY MsgCount DESC
```

which results in this incomplete result set:

```
ID          Typee                                                  MsgCount  
----------  -----------------------------------------------------  ----------
1           Position Report Class A                                156063    
5           Static and Voyage Related Data                         4761      
24          Static Data Report                                     3260
```

You can see that message type 1 is fom the messages table, but 5 and 24 are from the SVD table. The MsgCount for type 1 appears to be the sum of all message types from the "messages" table - so it did mix and mingle some data, but it appears to have combined all "messages" table results into one count?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the GROUP BY is applying only to the second select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `group by` in the first subquery.  I also recommend table aliases:

```
SELECT m.message_type AS ID, mt.type AS Type, count(*) as MsgCount
FROM messages m mt INNER JOIN
     message_types mt
     ON m.message_type = mt.ID
GROUP BY m.message_type AS ID, mt.type AS Type
UNION
SELECT svd.message_type AS ID, mt.type AS Type, count(*) as MsgCount
FROM svd INNER JOIN
     message_types mt
     ON svd.message_type = mt.ID
GROUP BY svd.message_type, mt.type
ORDER BY MsgCount DESC
```